# How to Implement JWT Token Authentication for API Routes and Pages in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm currently working on a Next.js application and I'm looking to implement JWT token authentication to protect my API routes and pages. I've researched various tutorials and documentation but I'm struggling to find a clear, concise solution tailored specifically for Next.js 13.

I have been through tutorials and blogs but I'm struggling to find a clear, concise solution tailored specifically for Next 13.
Could someone provide a step-by-step guide or example code demonstrating how to implement JWT token authentication in Next 13.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around and wrote this code and this might help others who is not wanting to use third party Auth.

Verify Token

```
import { jwtVerify } from "jose";
export const getJwtSecretKey = () => {
const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
if (!secret || secret.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("The environment variable JWT_SECRET is not set.");
}
return secret;
};
export async function verifyJwtToken(token:string) {
try {
    const verified = await jwtVerify(
        token,
        new TextEncoder().encode(getJwtSecretKey())
    );
    return verified.payload;
} catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Your token is expired");
}
}
```

middleware.ts

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
```

import {verifyJwtToken} from "@/lib/verifyToken"
export async function middleware (request:NextRequest) {

```
const path= request.nextUrl.pathname;
const publicPath= ["/" ,"/auth"];
const publicRoutes = ["/api/login","/api/register"]

const isPublicPath = publicPath.includes(path);
const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(path);
const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value;

const verifiedToken = token && 
( await verifyJwtToken(token).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Token verification error ",error)
}) 
)

if(path.startsWith("/api")) {
    if(isPublicRoute){
        return NextResponse.next();
    }
    else if(!isPublicRoute && !verifiedToken){
        return NextResponse.json({message:"Unauthorized user"},{status:401})
    }
}

if (isPublicPath && verifiedToken) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard",request.url))
}

if (!isPublicPath && !verifiedToken) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth",request.url))
}
}

export const config = {
matcher :["/","/auth","/dashboard","/api/:path*"]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [NextAuth.js](https://next-auth.js.org/) which is an open-source authentication solution specifically for Next.js.
You should be able to follow their [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/configuration/options#jwt) to configure NextAuth to use JWT.

In addition to docs, you could also look into this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MTyCvS05V4&ab_channel=CodeWithAntonio) of setting up Next auth - it's quite comprehensive. I believe the tutorial uses Next 14 but the concepts should be transferable to V 13.

Comment: i don't want to use third party library like next-auth currently as i am learning. I want to manually authenticate and authorize routes and pages